# Pattern matching on tail of arrays

Tags: scala

I was trying to implement distinct function on arrays like this:

```
def distinct(a: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = a match {
    case Array() => a
    case Array(head, tail @ _*) => head +: distinct(tail.toArray).filter(_ != head)
}
```

I don't like, that I have to transform tail toArray every time. Otherwise compiler complains that tail is just a sequence and not an array. Is it possible to pattern match better in this case?

Comment: Why don't you use Lists instead? In seems unnatural to process arrays in one-by-one recursive manner with head-tail slicing and further concating (note that you would have performance sinks with this approach)

Comment: Because I want to use arrays :) I know that with Lists I wouldn't have this problem

Comment: I'm just going through Scala for impatient and one of the tasks asks to calculate distinct values of an array (basically calling distinct method on array). I'm curious how it is implemented there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't sexy enough pattern matching, but I would go this way:

```
def distinct(a: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = a match {
    case Array() => a
    case htail   => htail.head +: distinct(htail.tail).filter(_ != htail.head)
}
```

Comment: actually I'm satisfied with your solution. I was just thinking if I could tell pattern matching, that the tail is also Array and not Seq. Something like: case Array(head, tail: Array[Int] @ _*)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't.  You're asking it to extract these things to new objects, but no suitable object really exists.

You could write your own extractor and a class that kept around an array plus a start index, but Scala doesn't really have this built in.  You're not really going to get all of the performance benefits of an array anyway because you're creating a new object for every single tail when you pattern match like this.

My suggestion would be to use the built-in `distinct` on arrays, but if you *really* want to write your own using pattern matching, I'd use the built-in conversion from `Array` to `WrappedArray`, then just implement a more generic implementation using `Seq` or `IndexedSeq`.

```
def distinct(a: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = distinct(a: Seq[Int]).toArray
```